# How do I choose which lands to tap?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012

Whenever I cast a spell, the game automatically taps an appropriate number of lands. However, it's often important to tap specific lands to leave correct mana available for additional spells. The game doesn't always do a very good job of picking the right lands to tap.

Is there any way I can manually choose which lands to tap when casting a spell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity and quicker multiplayer play, *Duels of the Planeswalkers 2011* and *2012* do not let you select which lands to tap.

This is had been a [bit of a contentious thing](http://community.wizards.com/go/forum/search?blogID=37034611&categoryID=75842&forumID=134962&terms=select+land&searchLevel=forum) in the official forums since the launch of the original game, and was not addressed in *Magic 2012*.

However, this deficiency [will be addressed in *Magic 2013*](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/06/07/duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013-adds-manual-mana-tapping/), which allows manual tapping across all platforms:

- On Xbox 360 and PlayStation 3, you press down on the left thumb stick.
- On iPad, you tap the land you want.
- On the PC, you press the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Comment: Bummer. I understand the game is aimed at casual players, but geez, couldn't they have made it a checkbox in the options or something?

Comment: Wow. this just changed my mind on buying it. Obviously they don't really care about aiming for the people who seriously play Magic.

Comment: Just lost a game because of this, couldn't play the second creature I needed to win because I didn't have the right mana-types remaining.  Wowowowow.

Comment: it actually requires more attention to your ordering than the others that do allow you to pick your mana to mitigate how the game chooses which mana to blow.  You have to make sure that you use the spells that require the most specific first and even with that you still show up short every once and again.

Comment: Wow. And to think I wanted to buy this during steam sale... I'm no avid MTG player, but I do know you need to be able to make specific tapping choices...

Comment: Mostly I've found it to be pretty good, it will generally avoid locking out any card in your hand if it can possibly avoid it.

But yes, this is definitely designed as an entry level game where they expect the user to dislike micromanaging and make mistakes when they do.