# Choose which lands goes to mana pool in Duels of the Plainwalker 2015 Arcade

Tags: xbox-360, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

So the question is simple. I really don't know how to select **which land I want tapped** when paying to cast a spell or ability, I'm playing in ***Magic The Gathering Duels of the Planeswalkers 2015 arcade for Xbox 360.***

**P.D**: I know some people have question this before, but as far as I check none of the question where regarding 2015 edition.

Comment: Does the first answer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26040/how-do-i-choose-which-lands-to-tap work in this version?

Comment: try looking in the settings. If I remember correctly there was a checkbox that would let you tap the lands yourself(and otherwise the game does it for you). After that you should be able to tap the lands you want

Comment: In fact it does, You need to press the left thumb stick. Care to add it like an answer? @Studoku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have have the PC version, but I assume the menus are structured the same way.
From the main menu, go to **"Help and Options"**, then the first bubble, **"Settings"**
Go to the farthest right page, titled **"Advanced"** and there should be an option called **"Auto Land"**
Uncheck that option to allow you to manually choose your lands.

Now in the PC version you need to hover over your card you want to play and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to choose the lands.  In the Xbox version I believe you need to click in the left thumb stick.

Example:
I want to play [Angelic Edict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Angelic%20Edict), a card with a cost of 4[image]
In my hand I have [Bloodghast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bloodghast), a card with a cost of [image][image] which I want to play aswell this turn.
On the field I have 7 lands, 3 Swamp and 4 Plains. Mana pool: [image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

When I highlight Angelic Edict (before I play it) the game will show me (by highlighting my lands in purple) that it will use [image][image][image][image][image] to play this card, and leave 2 extra white. This is not what I want.
So whilst Angelic Edict is highlighted, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the highlight swithes to [image][image][image][image][image], leaving me 1 white and 1 black.
Still not what I want, so pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> again highlights [image][image][image][image][image], leaving me with 2 black mana remaining, perfect to play my Bloodghast.